# Javascript slider shows white screens

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i'm building a javascript slider for my portfolio with Javascript. The slides work properly but when i add a fading transition i keep getting a white flash between the 2 slides. Anyone knows how to create a smooth fade between them?

I added a JSfiddle down below.

Here's my javascript:

```
     $(function () {
    var theInterval; // Slide speed
    var images = new Array();
    var counter = 1;
    var defaultSettings = {
        "sliderContainer": "#slider" // SliderContainer
        , "pauseWithMouse": true // Turn on/off pause with mouse
        , "sliderSpeed": 3000 // Slide speed
        , "transitionSpeed": 200 // transition speed
    };
    // intialize slider   
    // if myImages exists then
    images = myImages;
    if (images.length > 0) {
        $(defaultSettings.sliderContainer).append('<img id="sliderImg" width="900" src="' + images[0] + '" />');
        startSlide(images);
    }

    function cycleImages(images) {
        if (counter >= images.length) {
            counter = 0;
        }
        console.log(counter);
        document.getElementById("sliderImg").src = images[counter];
        counter++;
        var images = $('#sliderImg')
        var now = images.filter(':visible')
        var next = now.next().length ? now.next() : images.first()
        var speed = defaultSettings.transitionSpeed; //Transition speed
        now.fadeOut(speed);
        next.fadeIn(speed);
    }

    function startSlide() {
        console.log('start');
        theInterval = setInterval(function () {
            cycleImages(images);
        }, defaultSettings.sliderSpeed);
        // Set interval time
    };
    var stopSlide = function () { // Stop slides on hover
        console.log('stop');
        if (defaultSettings.pauseWithMouse) {
            clearInterval(theInterval);
        }
    };
    $('#sliderImg').on('mouseover', function () { // Stop slides on mouseover
        stopSlide();
    });
    $('#sliderImg').on('mouseout', function () { // Continue with slides on mouseout
        startSlide();
    });
});
```

[The JS Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/t9ezr8wr/)

Comment: check your JS Fiddle and edit it so I can help you.

Comment: @ZombieChowder Hey i added a working fiddle ; https://jsfiddle.net/t9ezr8wr/2/

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because there is no background while the fade in occurs. The easiest way to fix this is to add a `z-index` property to the image or the slide.

For example give the first image an **z-index of 1** and the second one a **z-index of 2**

Here is the code that you should implement:

```
var subs  = $(this).find('#sliderImg');
var index = subs.eq(0).css('z-index');
subs.gt(0).each(function() {
    $(this).css('z-index', ++index);
});
```

The idea is to access each element of the array via the tag you provided `#sliderImg` and using the jQuery method **each** to increase the **z-index css property** with 1.

Here is a working fiddle: [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t9ezr8wr/44/)

Comment: How is this possible when the images are in a array and i want to add more images?

Comment: @BjörnVanSteenberghe check it out now, it should work perfectly.